# Save As dialog box when downloading PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, itext

I'm trying to allow my webapp to download the PDF file with a save as dialog. However, after trying, there wasn't any save as dialog box then appeared when i used chrome/firefox. But when i use IE, i was given this error

[image]

Could it be some error between the browser? I have saved / convert my PDF file into bytes.

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Byte array that will eventually hold our PDF, currently empty
        Byte[] bytes;

        //Instead of a FileStream we'll use a MemoryStream
        using (var MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {

            //Standard PDF setup, iText doesn't care what type of stream we're using
            var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, MS);
            doc.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.TotalWidth = 585f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;

            var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
            doc.Add(logo);

            var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Font.BOLD);
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Officer's Profile. Officer's Police ID: " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

            var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
            var phrase = new Phrase();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lrp.fullname,  pp.profilepic, pp.rank, lrp.policeid, lrp.nric, lrp.email, lrp.contact, lrp.address,lrp.location, pp.achievement, pp.medal1, pp.medal2, pp.medal3, pp.medal4, pp.medal5 from LoginRegisterPolice lrp, PoliceProfile pp where lrp.policeid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and pp.policeid = lrp.policeid", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;

            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Profile Picture :\u00a0", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[1];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
                image1.ScaleToFit(100f, 250f);
                Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk1);

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Rank : ", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes2 = (Byte[])dr[2];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes2);
                image2.ScaleToFit(40f, 300f);
                Chunk imageChunk2 = new Chunk(image2, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk2);

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police ID :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("NRIC :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Email :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[6].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Address :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[7].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Location :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[8].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Achievement :", normalFont));
                phrase.Add(dr[9].ToString());

                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);



                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal1", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes3 = (Byte[])dr[10];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image3 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes3);
                image3.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
                Chunk imageChunk3 = new Chunk(image3, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk3);


                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal2", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[11];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
                image5.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
                Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk5);



                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal3", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes6 = (Byte[])dr[12];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image6 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes6);
                image6.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
                Chunk imageChunk6 = new Chunk(image6, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk6);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal4", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes7 = (Byte[])dr[13];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image7 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes7);
                image7.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
                Chunk imageChunk7 = new Chunk(image7, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk7);

                phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal5", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes8 = (Byte[])dr[14];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image8 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes8);
                image8.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
                Chunk imageChunk8 = new Chunk(image8, 0, 0);
                phrase.Add(imageChunk8);

                table.AddCell(phrase);


            }

            dr.Close();
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();

            //Grab the raw bytes from the MemoryStream
            bytes = MS.ToArray();
        }



        //At this point all iText work is done and we're only dealing with raw ASP.Net parts

        //Clear the current response buffer
        Response.Clear();
        //Instead of a normal text/html header tell the browser that we've got a PDF
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //Tell the browser that you want the file downloaded (ideally) and give it a pretty filename
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MySampleFile.pdf");
        //Write our bytes to the stream
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        //Close the stream (otherwise ASP.Net might continue to write stuff on our behalf)
        Response.End();
    }




}
```

Would appreciate if anyone could tell me if i did anything wrong here.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem on more than one PC? The dialog in question looks like a native code extension (e.g. your PDF reader software) crashed.

Comment: When i tested the webapp online, nothing happened when i clicked the PDF button in both Chrome and IE. The error only appears when i run it on the localhost in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your ContentType. If you change it to to "application/octet-stream", that should resolve your problem.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

You can also try adding:

```
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```

before `Response.End()`. It could be that not all of the buffered data has been transmitted to the client before ending the response.

If that doesn't work, you should verify that you actually have data to send in the `bytes` array.

Comment: After adding the octet-stream, the error still persist on the localhost when i run on IE.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: Updated the answer with additional things to try.

Answer (score -1):

Use This,

```
string fileName = string.Format(Guid.NewGuid()+".pdf");
htmlToPdf(Server.MapPath(@"~\temp\") + fileName);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```